# Find the derivative of $\int \cdots \int_{x_1^2+\cdots + x_m^2 \le r^2} f(x_1,\ldots,x_m) \ dx_1 dx_2 \ldots dx_m$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $f:\mathbb{R^m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Find the derivative of $$F(r) := \int \cdots \int_{x_1^2+\cdots + x_m^2 \le r^2} f(x_1,\ldots,x_m) \ dx_1 dx_2 \ldots dx_m.$$

I have no idea how to do that. Could you help me?

Comment: Derivative with respect to $r$, or what?

Comment: If with respect to $r$, switch to $m$-dimensinal spherical coordinates, and then differentiate the radial integral using Leibnitz Rule.

Comment: @HansLundmark: yes with respect to $r$, I ll make an edit

Comment: It is just the multiple integral over $x_1^2+\ldots+x_m^2\color{red}{=}r^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\phi(x) = rx$ and then the change of variables gives
$\int_A f(x)dx = \int_{\phi^{-1}(A)} f(\phi(y)) | \det D \phi(y)| dy$.

Assuming I have made no mistakes this gives $F(r) = \int_{B(0,1)} f(rx) r^n dx$.

Now using Leibniz we have
$F'(r) = \int_{B(0,1)} (Df(rx)(x) r^n +n f(rx)r^{n-1})dx$.

Comment: Except that it seems you should have $n=m$ ... :)

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thamks for catchimg ny nistake!