# Derivative of $\underset{x_1^2+...+x_m^2\leq r^2}{\int ...\int} f(x_1,...,x_m) dx_1 \, dx_2 ... dx_m$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, leibniz-integral-rule

I want to calculate the derivative
$$F(r)=\underset{x_1^2+...+x_m^2\leq r^2}{\int ... \int} f(x_1,...,x_m) \, dx_1 \, dx_2 ... dx_m$$
with respect to $r$. $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continous function.

---

My attempt: (heavily inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3499724/find-the-derivative-of-int-cdots-int-x-12-cdots-x-m2-le-r2-fx-1-l))

We can define the function

$$\phi: \mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m,\quad x\mapsto rx$$

$x_1^2+...+x_m^2 \leq r^2$ $\Rightarrow$ $\sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_m^2} \leq r$ $\overset{\phi^{-1}}{\Longrightarrow}$ $\sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_m^2} \leq \phi^{-1}(r) = 1$
So the region we're integrating is $B_{\mathbb{R}^m}(0,1)$, right? (I know my definition of $\phi$ can be misleading, maybe someone has a better suggestion?)

We can then change variables and see that...
\begin{align*}
\underset{x_1^2+...+x_m^2 \leq r^2}{\int ... \int} f(x_1,...,x_m) dx_1...dx_m= \underset{B_{\mathbb{R}^m}(0,1)}{\int ... \int} f(rx_1,...,rx_m) \cdot |\det D\phi(x_1,...,x_m)| dx_1...dx_m
\end{align*}

We can easily calculate that...
\begin{align*}
\det \phi(x_1,...,x_m) = \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
r & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 0\\
0& r & 0 & ... & 0 & 0\\
....\\
0&0&0&...&r&0\\
0&0&0&...&0&r\\
\end{pmatrix}}_{\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}} = r^m
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\underset{x_1^2+...+x_m^2 \leq r^2}{\int ... \int} f(x_1,...,x_m) dx_1...dx_m = \underset{B_{\mathbb{R}^m}(0,1)}{\int ... \int} r^m\cdot f(rx_1,...,rx_m) dx_1...dx_m
\end{align*}

Now that the bounds are free from $r$, we can move $\frac{d}{dr}$ inside the integral.
\begin{align*}
F'(r)&=\frac{d}{dr} \underset{B_{\mathbb{R}^m}(0,1)}{\int ... \int} r^m\cdot f(rx_1,...,rx_m) dx_1...dx_m = \underset{B_{\mathbb{R}^m}(0,1)}{\int ... \int} \frac{d}{dr} r^m\cdot f(rx_1,...,rx_m) dx_1...dx_m\\
&\underset{B_{\mathbb{R}^m}(0,1)}{\int ... \int} f'(rx_1,...,rx_m)\cdot (x_1\cdot ... \cdot x_m)\cdot r^m + m\cdot r^{m-1}\cdot f(rx_1,...,rx_m) dx_1...dx_m
\end{align*}

Any remarks? Is this correct?

Comment: Use polar coordinates

Comment: Presumably when you write $f’$ you really mean to invoke the chain rule on each coordinate.

Comment: Have you considered using spherical coordinates? For example, in $\Bbb R^2$, you would have $$\frac d{dr} \int_0^r \int_0^{2\pi} uf(u\cos\theta,u\sin\theta)\,d\theta\,du = \int_0^{2\pi} rf(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)\,d\theta,$$ which is the integral of $f$ over the boundary circle of radius $r$.

Comment: @AlexR. that's correct.

Comment: @TedShifrin I see what you mean, I'll try doing it on this way. But it's not wrong if I do it like I did here, is it?

Comment: I think your formula, although correct, is not very enlightening. You should understand that the change comes just as you understand how the area of a circle of radius $r$ changes, namely with circumference times $\Delta r$. Thus, the surface integral of $f$ over the boundary of the ball is the natural way to understand this.

Comment: @TedShifrin okay, thank you!

Comment: @TedShifrin You're right that looking at the formula doesn't really tell you what's happening. I'll try with spherical coordinates.

Comment: @Quotenbanane: I meant to write $g(r)=\int^r_0\int_{\mathbb{S}_{n-1}}s^{n-1}f(s\mathbf{u})\,\sigma_{n-1}(d\mathbf{u})\,ds$. For more complicated regions, there is the coarea formula.